# What is the use of password hashing if it could be easily decrypted ?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash

The password is the `mySQL` database should be kept in the hashed form

```
echo password_hash('test', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

gives us

```
$2y$10$8PxsFGPbGtgYb44GRPL84ev2T0xR0LXMSSKm7cuSBUbAU114mosFG
```

or

```
$2y$10$E.q3bVE9EE2ce2VaKPJgtuwEMRZxpTYiQR6Mw2dmLGqeKx/PsQY42
```

or . . .

But all of those `$2y$10. . .` strings are easily decrypted back to `test` using `password_verify` .

Let's say somebody gets access to the hashed passwords , then she will be able to decrypt them using `password_verify`  ? Once somebody has the string `$2y$10$E.q3bVE9EE2ce2VaKPJgtuwEMRZxpTYiQR6Mw2dmLGqeKx/PsQY42` he or she can easily convert it back to a plain text, right ? So why hashing password ?

Comment: `password_verify` does not decrypt, it rehashes to see it they match. That's the point of a hash, it can't really be reversed.

Comment: maybe you simply can decode sha1 hash of for example "mypassword", but it's so hard to decode something like this: "#qrti6tr2<>++" as a password.

Comment: **he or she can easily convert it back to a plain text, right ?** simply *no*, not right

Comment: The `password_verify` function requires the unhashed password to be able to verify (as it cannot obtain it from the hash). Without it, no verification can be performed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement

> But all of those $2y$10. . . strings are easily decrypted back to test using password_verify .

is not true.

Because `password_hash()` is one-way hashing.

That means there is (practically) no way to go back from the hashed string to the original string.

`password_verify()` **does not decrypt** the hash (as it's not possible). More simply it hashes the password to be verified and checks if the resulting hash matches with the one provided.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a misconception of what data comes in and what comes out of the `password_verify` function. During "decryption" you pass in the actual password that the hash is supposed to represent. The password has to be known for it to be verified.

What `password_verify` does, is hashing the password that you give it again using the same method as the hash given and check if both match.

So it is not possible to easily reverse the hash with `password_verify`. You would have to brute-force through the passwords to find a password that matches the hash.

Note: if we talk about password hashing, this cannot be called encryption, because it is one-way and encryption would have a corresponding decryption function.